# Nautilus covers the background with black or white 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, nautilus, compiz, desktop-background

In 16.04, my background comes as a black or white color. I tried something and it(nautilus) crashed and I could see my background again. Can anyone tell what is happening here and how can I fix it.

And just for information I have already tried deleting all the compiz, gconf and dconf configurations and also setting background active true from terminal. They didn't work for me

Comment: Why not try dolphin.

Comment: what?? I want to fix nautilus. I like it because it's simple

Comment: Your choice. As you wish.